# executing ant clean, Build Failed, Wrong java Version

Tags: java, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to install hybris, but while installing I face a problem in executing **ant clean** command.

I am using the latest version of java which should work.
I have also used setantenv.bat in the right path.

here is the stack trace :

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.1 compiled on May 15 2013

C:\work\trail\hybris\bin\platform>**ant clean**
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128M; support
s removed in 8.0
Buildfile: C:\work\trail\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml
     [echo] C:\work\trail\hybris\bin\platform/tomcat/bin

**BUILD FAILED**
C:\work\trail\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:20: The following error occurred w
le executing this line:
C:\work\trail\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\antmacros.xml:73: The followin
error occurred while executing this line:
C:\work\trail\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\util.xml:234: -

**** **WRONG JAVA VERSION** ****

 Environment check failed: You are using a not supported version of Java.
 Please make sure you are using Java version 1.7 or later.
 Your current Java version is: 1.8.0_40

 TIP: If you are using eclipse you can configure a different JVM under
 Preferences->Java->Installed JREs.

Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: Please give us at least a portion of the stack trace.  My first guess is that you are having a versioning mismatch between Hybris and your JDK.

Comment: Thanks !!, I have uploaded the complete stack trace after ant clean execution.

Comment: What version of Hybris are you using?

Comment: hybris-commerce-suite-5.2.0.6

Comment: Try using JDK 7 instead of 8 and see what happens.

Comment: ok, let me just try !

Comment: Its working BUILD SUCCESSFUL. Thanks a lot u save my hours.   But still I am unable to get what was the problem ?

Comment: [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61190824/13302453) try this instead, worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you were able to get Hybris working with JDK 7, it appears that Java JDK version 1.8.0_40 does not have backwards compatibility/support for Hybris 5.2.0.6.  You may want to open a bug with Hybris if you are feeling entrepid.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse go to platform - build.xml - right click on it - go to run as - external tools configuration - go to jre tab - add in separate jre the required jre version - add the build.xml file again to ant and run it

Answer (score 0):

[check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61190824/13302453)

try this instead, adding java version in util.xml under platfrom folder. worked for me!